# WP7 pivot IsHitTestVisible to false doesn't work, pivot remembers my moves when set back to true

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an app, where I have a pivot.
When a new pivot loads I set the IsHitTestVisible to false and open a popup while loading some data.
When the loading is complete I reset the property to true.

The problem is that in between this time, if I do a gesture on the pivot, after the loading completes, the pivot remembers my moves and slides the pivot or clicks on items in the pivot.

How is this possible?

I just want to disable the pivot, while loading my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't supported very well today, but a future update may address the manipulations issue.

A visual tree organized differently might help, if you can get the manipulations handled before being passed on along the visual tree.

```
Grid
    Pivot
    Grid IsHitTestVisible = False // your overlay
    Grid // your "popup"
```

And if this does not work, although the performance may not be great, having your "loading" page in a dedicated Popup, the manipulations will not be sent to the Pivot even if its underneath.

Comment: my popup "loading" page is the last child of my root grid. I placed it inside a grid. and an overlay grid before this where i set the hittest to false. it doesn't work. i tried to set all possible elements to ishittestvisible to false, including the layoutroot grid, but it's always the same result.

Comment: for some reason, the loading popup catches only a few of my clicks as I see in my debug output. after 1-2 seconds, it doesn't although the popup is still open.. maybe this is caused by a delay of the popup window to become invisible?

Comment: it'd be best to test on the device since the emulator/mouse combo isn't as accurate. feel free to share some xaml example too maybe?

Comment: i created a canvas of height 800px and placed it on top of my page with visibility set to "collapsed". Then whenever I load some data, I set the visibility to "visible"  and my pivot goes out of the screen. When the loading completes, i set it back. This seems to work. Thanx for your help!